# CakePHP / MySQL getting loosely associated data

Tags: mysql, cakephp

so I have two tables in my database, the first is created upon payment for a subscription and has the user's email as a reference. The user then creates an account after the fact. So a foreign key isn't set.

I want to generate a query that will fetch the data from this subscription generating table. I'm trying something like this:

```
    // Querying the members table, trying to include member_subsr data
    $oMembers = $Members->find('all',
        [
            'contains' => ['member_subscr'],
            'conditions' => [
                'member_email' => 'members.email'
            ],
            'order' =>
                [
                    'id' => 'DESC'
                ]
        ]);
```

Error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'member_email' in 'where clause'`

Not sure where to go from here. I want to associate the entries by user email rather than a foreign key.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest to start with figuring what the plain SQL should look like, and what data exactly you need to fetch, and if you're unable to translate it to CakePHPs ORM/query builder, present it alongside your question. btw, if the email address is unique (what I'd assume), it surely could act as a foreign key.

Comment: This seems to work, `SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN member_attributes ON member_attributes.member_email = members.email`

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. When dealing with a different foreignKey than usual, you must set the foreignKey and a new BindingKey within the MembersTable initialization function.

```
    // In MembersTable
     $this->hasOne('member_attributes')
        ->setForeignKey('member_email')
        ->setBindingKey('email');
    // in Controller
    $oMembers = $Members->find('all')->contain(['member_attributes']);
```